# Is it possible to create un-skippable full screen alerts in windows?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

I want to create a notification or an alert for the user to restart the PC if it hasn't been done so for 5 days.I used windows toast to do this but found out that toasts can be dismissed and there is no way to perform an action upon dismissal, this is not good as the user can just dismiss the toast without restart the pc for n number of days. I need to implement something similar to the "Low/Ciritical battery" or the "Low Disk Space" Notification (see pictures attached).

[image: Low Disk Space Image]
[image: AV Image]

I have tried some searching on how to implement this alert but almost all the sources use toast notifications to display the alert. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: please share how you create the thoast for a minimal repeatable example

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/256565/schedule-pc-reboot-via-group-policy-with-user-inte ?

Comment: @DenisSchaf I have created the toast using a simple Powershell script. I do not want to use toast anymore as it can be dismissed without performing any action thus it defeats the purpose of what I want to do.

Comment: @MarcGravell This seems like exactly what I want, I will give it a try and give an update. Thanks...